# How to restrict child elements from skew while parent element scales

Tags: javascript, html, matrix, svg

Is there a way to restrict rotated child elements from skewing when parent element is scaled?

This is my code

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 500 500">
<g class="parent" transform="matrix(1.71341 0 0 1 -42.302 0)">
    <path d="M59.295623779296875,59.295623779296875 L470,59.295623779296875 L470,470 L59.295623779296875,470Z"></path>        
    <g class="shape1" transform="matrix(-0.774634 0.63241 -0.63241 -0.774634 481.409 228.445)">
        <ellipse rx="100" ry="100" cx="200" cy="200"></ellipse>            
    </g>
    <g class="shape2" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)">
        <ellipse rx="70" ry="70" cx="400" cy="400"></ellipse>        
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

I created a JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tYqdk/30/
. In the fiddle shape1 (Ellipse with color green) is rotated. When apply scale to the parent element shape1 become skewed.

When the rotation of child element is 90,180,270, or 360 there is no issues.

Is there any way to fix this issue?.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a child element to appear unaffected by the parent's transform, then you will need to apply an inverse transform to the child.

Why is the child even inside the group if it isn't meant to be affected by changes to the group properties?  Move it outside the group or move the transform down to the children you want it to affect.

Comment: To preserve descendant element's size while scaling parent element, i applied inverse matrix. http://jsfiddle.net/uPSc4/10/. But i dont know how to find inverse matrix to restrict skew alone. I need all the other transformations except skew to get applied on child elements.